# OneDrive Graph API - Checkin and Checkout not working

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I'm trying to use OneDrive with GraphApi to read items, upload items etc via C# and all works great.

I'm following this.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-checkin?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp

```
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> Checkin(string Id)
  {
     //Id looks like this: B381F21397737D41!111

     var itemInfo = Id.Split('!');
     var versions = _graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Items[Id].Versions.Request().GetAsync().Result;
     var permissions = _graphServiceClient.Me.Drive.Items[Id].Permissions.Request().GetAsync().Result;
     var drives = _graphServiceClient.Me.Drives.Request().GetAsync().Result;
  
     var comment = "Updating with the latest.";
     await _graphServiceClient.Drives[itemInfo[0]].Items[itemInfo[1]]
        .Checkin(null, comment)
        .Request()
        .PostAsync();

     return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
```

But when I do Checkin or Checkout, it shows this error. All goes well till it gets to the async 'checkin' part.

```
ServiceException: Code: invalidRequest Message: API not found Inner 

error: AdditionalData: date: 2022-05-24T08:14:59 request-id: edac8ef2-13f5-46c9-aa1f-dcef248427aa client-request-id: edac8ef2-13f5-46c9-aa1f-dcef248427aa ClientRequestId: edac8ef2-13f5-46c9-aa1f-dcef248427aa
Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

[image: Error in full]

Is this because the checkin/checkout is only supported for the beta endpoint ?

Any help appreciated !

Comment: What type of OneDrive do you have? Personal, Business, etc.?

Comment: @user2250152 the host application is using a business account, while the guest user who is logging in is having a personal outlook account.

Comment: Other code issue: You have an async function, but you call `.GetAsync().Result` instead of `await .GetAsync()`

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/574546/is-checkin-checkout-files-supported-by-onedrive-pe

In OneDrive Microsoft personal account, there is no Checkin/Checkout features for files.